# Hide part of HTML Select Option

Tags: html, database, filter, html-select, hidden

I want to hide part a dropdown list select option and then use the hidden part to filter the list. i.e. A list of names with a hidden location for each name. Then I can use Javascript to filter the list based on the location of the people. I tried the following:

```
<form>
<select>
<option value='x'> Visible Name <p hidden> Invisible Location</p></option>
</select>
</form>
```

However it's not allowing me to hide inside the option element. Is there a way to hide HTML here? I tried hidden and display:none, neither was working. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "Is there a better way to filter through a mySQL database server-side?" Yes, write the query in a way it doesn't retrieve unwanted data. But since your not giving any information what the criteria is, this cannot be answered.

Comment: @stickybit The query selects three fields. The id which is the value of the select option, the name of the person which is the displayed data, and a location which I want to be able to filter by without submitting again to the server, but not display it in the select box.

Comment: Just don't select the location then? But maybe I#M not getting it. Try to include the relevant part, which is querying the database, in your question and possibly rephrase the question so that it's clear what exactly you need/want to show.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks, Is this easier to understand?

Comment: Not really, I suppose... Still keeps me saying, if you don't want the location, don't include it in the `SELECT`. BTW, probably post that `SELECT`.

Answer (score -1):

you can't do that.
try this https://select2.org/ or https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/